thme is not switching back and forth in tkinter
I have created a Gym Management Software using Tkinter, and I am using custom themes (forest-dark and forest-light) for the UI. I use an OptionMenu to allow users to switch between these themes dynamically. The theme change works the first time (from dark to light or vice versa), but when I attempt to switch back to the original theme (e.g., from light back to dark), the UI does not update accordingly.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
class GymManagementApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # App configuration
        self.title("Gym Management Software")
        self.geometry("800x800")
        self.style = ttk.Style()

        # Load the initial theme from environment
        self.theme = get_env("THEME")

        if self.theme is None:
            theme_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "theme/forest-dark.tcl")
            set_env("THEME", "forest-dark")  # set default theme
        else:
            theme_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"theme/{self.theme}.tcl")

        # Load and apply the theme
        self.tk.call("source", theme_path)
        self.style.theme_use(self.theme)

    def update_theme(self, theme):
        """Switch the application's theme."""
        print(f"Theme changed to: {theme}")
        print(self.style.theme_names())

        # Load the new theme if not already loaded
        theme_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f"theme/{theme}.tcl")
        if theme not in self.style.theme_names():
            print(f"Loading theme: {theme}")
            self.tk.call("source", theme_path)

        # Apply the new theme
        self.style.theme_use(theme)

        # Store the new theme in the environment variable
        self.theme = theme
        set_env("THEME", theme)

        # Ensure the UI is updated immediately
        self.update_idletasks()

Output:
When I change the theme the first time, it works fine:
Theme changed to: Light
('clam', 'alt', 'default', 'forest-dark', 'classic')
Loading theme: forest-light

But when I try to switch back to the previous theme, the UI doesn't update:
Theme changed to: Dark
('forest-light', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'forest-dark', 'classic')


Note that tkinter window is not a themed widget, so changing theme does not affect it.  However its background is changed when sourcing the theme script.  You can see the change of theme if you create a ttk.Frame that fill the entire window.
